# Prevent app from launching

Tags: android

I'm looking for a solution that allows an application (my application) to prevent an app from launching. I want the whole package to be unable to be launched, not just its launcher intent.

However I have some restrictions:

- Application cannot replace home
- Application cannot be system

What the application has access to:

- Root
- Device Administrator
- Anything else within the regular Android userspace

It is something related to MDMs, or device policies restricting certain applications, however I want to disable system apps from launching, say, Settings, or Calculator.

The current solution, which I'd like to replace, uses the ActivityManager's running processes list, and is ran every 500ms to check if any of the specific apps were launched. This has changed slightly for API 22 and up, as Lollipop MR1 (5.1) includes the usage statistics service, from where it is easier to query the last launched app. Then the service proceeds to launch the current launcher activity, thus "disabling" the application.

I believe it would be better if the app launch itself caused the trigger to kill the process (remember, we have root and device admin rights), however I can't find any description about doing so.

Answer (score 0):

If your application has root access you can disable an other application by executing command

```
"pm disable " + packageName
```

To execute command you can use this method :

```
public void execute(String command){
    try{
        Process su = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(su.getOutputStream());

        outputStream.writeBytes(command);
        outputStream.flush();

        outputStream.writeBytes("exit\n");
        outputStream.flush();
        su.waitFor();
    }catch(IOException e){
        throw new Exception(e);
    }catch(InterruptedException e){
        throw new Exception(e);
    }
}
```

This will disable package that can not be launched anymore.

If you want to check if an application is system you can use ApplicationInfo flags :

```
public static boolean isSystemApp(String packageName){
    try {
        ApplicationInfo app = this.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0);        
        return info.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0;
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not want to disable the specific package, especially with system apps. For example, Settings. Say, I have a store, where phones are on display, and I want the fookin kids to stop turning on the screen lock password/pattern 5 minutes after opening, or tampering with any other settings. For this, I want the phones to be unable to launch the Settings app. Or any other app I deem to be dangerous and not required for the purpose of the demo unit (e.g. Play Store).

Comment: You can add a button on you mdm to turn off some packages for your demo and an other to turn them on when you want.

Comment: I'va developped a MDM and the only solution to do not allow an application to start is to disable it. My MDM disable settings in some case and enable it when I need it.

Comment: The current solution (launching home as soon as an app launch is detected) works, but it is ugly, and uses some resources. 

The phones should display their whole selection of apps, but some of those that would cause issues if users were to play around (e.g. lockscreen settings) should not be allowed to run. Disabling the Settings app would cause lots of issues with the system.